# Pandas: fill in NaN values with values from dict of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This question was inspired by [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848911/pandas-fill-in-nan-values-with-dictionary-references-another-column).

Say that I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
   TYPE  YEAR  DAY  VALUE
0  a     2004  10   NaN
1  b     2005  12   NaN
2  c     2006  180  NaN
3  a     2007  127  NaN
4  b     2008  221  NaN
5  c     2008  17   NaN
```

and that I have to fill in the `VALUE` column based on the following dict of dicts, which has the format `{YEAR: {DAY, VALUE}}`:

```
mydict={2004: {10: 7.1},
        2005: {12: 9.19},
        2006: {127: 16.04, 180: 12.33},
        2007: {55: 21.94, 127: 33.11},
        2008: {17: 5.13, 221: 19.17, 300: 10.05}}
```

The answer given in the post above is to use `df.VALUE = df.VALUE.fillna(df.YEAR.map(mydict))`.

How can I change this mapping to make sure it "follows" both the YEAR and DAY columns in my dataframe?

If I apply the snippet above I get of course:

```
   TYPE  YEAR  DAY  VALUE
0  a     2004  10   {10: 7.1}
1  b     2005  12   {12: 9.19}
2  c     2006  180  {127: 16.04, 180: 12.33}
3  a     2007  127  {55: 21.94, 127: 33.11}
4  b     2008  221  {17: 5.13, 221: 19.17, 300: 10.05}
5  c     2008  17   {17: 5.13, 221: 19.17, 300: 10.05}
```

Instead, I am aiming for the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *rewrite* that column using `assign`:

```
df['VALUE'] = df.apply(lambda x: mydict[x.YEAR][x.DAY], axis=1)
```

Or as @Maarten Fabré noticed:

```
df['VALUE'] = df.apply(lambda x: mydict[x.YEAR].get(x.DAY, np.nan), axis=1)
```

Comment: Does this ignore `KeyError`? If not, you can better use `dict.get(key, default)` to prevent those

Comment: I added one `get()`, but surely could've gone with two :)

Answer (score 2):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(mydict).stack().to_frame()
df.assign(VALUE=df.set_index(['DAY', 'YEAR']).VALUE.fillna(df1[0]).values)
Out[937]: 
  TYPE  YEAR  DAY  VALUE
0    a  2004   10   7.10
1    b  2005   12   9.19
2    c  2006  180  12.33
3    a  2007  127  33.11
4    b  2008  221  19.17
5    c  2008   17   5.13
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame.lookup`

```
df.assign(VALUE=pd.DataFrame(mydict).lookup(df.DAY, df.YEAR))

  TYPE  YEAR  DAY  VALUE
0    a  2004   10   7.10
1    b  2005   12   9.19
2    c  2006  180  12.33
3    a  2007  127  33.11
4    b  2008  221  19.17
5    c  2008   17   5.13
```

---

**Option 2**
comprehension + `zip`

```
df.assign(VALUE=[mydict[y][d] for y, d in zip(df.YEAR, df.DAY)])

  TYPE  YEAR  DAY  VALUE
0    a  2004   10   7.10
1    b  2005   12   9.19
2    c  2006  180  12.33
3    a  2007  127  33.11
4    b  2008  221  19.17
5    c  2008   17   5.13
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the info from my_dict into a series with the year and day as index

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict).transpose().stack(0)
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(mydict).unstack().dropna() # works too
```

Then make Year and Day index for the original df, insert the sacond index, and transfrom the result back to the original shape

```
df3 = df.set_index(['DAY', 'YEAR'])
df3['VALUE'] = df2
df3.reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```