# How to fill missing values with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
year = [2015, 2016, 2009, 2000, 1998, 2017, 1980, 2016, 2015, 2015]
mode = ["automatic", "automatic", "manual", "manual", np.nan,'automatic', np.nan, 'automatic', np.nan, np.nan]

X = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'mode': mode})

print(X)

   year       mode
0  2015  automatic
1  2016  automatic
2  2009     manual
3  2000     manual
4  1998        NaN
5  2017  automatic
6  1980        NaN
7  2016  automatic
8  2015        NaN
9  2015        NaN
```

I want to fill missing values with like this: if year is <2010 I want to fill NaN with 'manual' and if year is >=2010 I want to fill NaN value with 'automatic'

I thought about combination .groupby function with these condition but I do not know honestly how to do it :(

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar approach to my answer on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327956/how-to-fill-missing-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-group-value-counts):

```
cond = X['year'] < 2010
X['mode'] = X['mode'].fillna(cond.map({True:'manual', False: 'automatic'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `np.where` and `fillna`

```
s=pd.Series(np.where(X.year<2010,'manual','automatic'),index=X.index)
X['mode'].fillna(s,inplace=True)
X
Out[192]: 
   year       mode
0  2015  automatic
1  2016  automatic
2  2009     manual
3  2000     manual
4  1998     manual
5  2017  automatic
6  1980     manual
7  2016  automatic
8  2015  automatic
9  2015  automatic
```

Comment: Just noticed that `s` can't be an array. Weird.

Comment: @timgeb index problem ~ :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`

```
X['mode'] = X['mode'].fillna(pd.Series(np.where(X['year'] >= 2010, 'automatic', 'manual')))
```

Output

```
   year       mode
0  2015  automatic
1  2016  automatic
2  2009     manual
3  2000     manual
4  1998     manual
5  2017  automatic
6  1980     manual
7  2016  automatic
8  2015  automatic
9  2015  automatic
```